# Setting different <span> tags for li and ul li (nested)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, html-lists

I really need to nail this... I've been at it way too long now.

**I think I need to get the innerText of each `<a>` element and put it into li_text variable.**

The following is the 'supplied' code for this theme. The theme does not support submenus.
BUT I need this so I'm trying to make it work with submenus.

The following js script is partly 'building' the HTML.

```
var$ $main_menu = $('#main_menu');

  $main_menu.find('li').each( function(){
    var $this_li = $(this),
li_text = $this_li.find('a').html();

$this_li.find('a').html( '<span class="main_text">' + li_text + '</span>' + '<span class="menu_slide">' + li_text + '</span>' )
    } );
```

**It seems that it's this piece of code: li_text = $this_li.find('a').html(); from the above. that needs to tweaking.... 
I need that line to take the 'a' from it's closest parent above..... does this make sense?**

together with this (from header.php)

```
$primaryNav = '';
  if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
    $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '',  'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'menu_id' => $menuID, 'echo' => false )   );}
```

The navigation HTML comes out like this:

```
<nav id="main_menu" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">
  <ul id="menu-dk-fl370" class="clearfix">
    <li id="menu-item-23" class="mcdu_left menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23 even">
    <li id="menu-item-48" class="mcdu_right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48 odd">
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="nolink menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27 even">
    <li id="menu-item-55" class="has_sub mcdu_right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55 odd">
      <a href="http://fl370.com/?page_id=53">
        <span class="main_text">MEDIA</span>
        <span class="menu_slide">MEDIA</span>
      </a>
        <ul id="sub-menu" class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
          ***<li id="menu-item-67" class="mcdu_sub mcdu_right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67">
            <a href="http://fl370.com/?page_id=60">
              <span class="main_text">
                <span class="main_text">MEDIA</span>
                <span class="menu_slide">MEDIA</span>
              </span>
              <span class="menu_slide">
                <span class="main_text">MEDIA</span>
                <span class="menu_slide">MEDIA</span>
              </span>
            </a>
         </li>***
         <li id="menu-item-66" class="mcdu_sub mcdu_right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66">
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and so on...

**

THIS IS WHAT IM TRYING TO GET....

```
              <span class="main_text">
                <span class="main_text">BILLEDER</span>
                <span class="menu_slide">BILLEDER</span>
              </span>
              <span class="menu_slide">
                <span class="main_text">VIDEO</span>
                <span class="menu_slide">VIDEO</span>
              </span>
```

These 'names' is inserted via the li_text function in js.
But it seems it's inserting only the first li a name.

I need the script to take the page name from its 'own'/parent li a.
AND still apply the js script....

**

Hope someone can help....

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a sample of HTML you are getting and mark the tags incorrectly added?

Comment: Can you also post the HTML that you are expecting to end up with?

Comment: Also note that you cannot use 2 or more ID's called the same thing (id="menu-item-xx")

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I hate using `html()` to populate snippets of HTML. I much rather prefer creating the elements, and appending them to the DOM. You end up with more control and understanding of what you're doing.

```
$("#main_menu li").each( 
    function(i, element)
    {
        $("<a />").attr("href", "some link here").appendTo(element);
        $("<span />").addClass("class name here").text("some text here").appendTo(element);
        // ...etc.
    }
);
```

*(If you post a little more about what code you're expecting in the end, I can give you more specifics about what I mean here...)*

That aside, you're probably having extra issues because your HTML is malformed. You close your `<a>` tag twice, and you don't close your `<li>` tag. Also, you don't close a `<span>` tag, because one of your angle brackets is reversed (`>/span>`). jQuery is going to have a tough time dissecting the HTML elements if they're not done properly.

Comment: Doesn't this cause a re-flow calculation on each appendTo()?  It seems like this approach would be computationally expensive.  I tend to use the .html([].push('').join('')) approach to building markup (you are right that it forces you to be correct)

Comment: OK - thanks guys

Here's the actual HTML I get. The above was just written off from another screen.... hence the "typos" sorry.

How can I post the code here? - I'm only able to show a limited number of characters....

Comment: edit the question with corrected code, it seems you are only having difficulties targetting the right tag, which should be an easy fix if you can specify exactly what you want to target

Answer (score 0):

If your code structure stays as it is then you can grab that content by doing this. I am assuming you can't use the class names or IDs

```
$main_menu.find('> ul > ul').html();
```

or

```
$('#main_menu > ul > ul').html();
```

this will return everything inside of the ul but not the ul itself, so you need to create it and add it.

```
var container_ul = '<ul class="' + $main_menu.find('> ul > ul').attr("class") + '" id="' + $main_menu.find('> ul > ul').attr("id") + '">';
```

define container_ul outside of the loop, so the final thing would look something like this

```
var $main_menu = $('#main_menu');
var container_ul = '';
var final_content = '';

$main_menu.find('> ul > ul').each( function(){
    container_ul = '<ul class="' + $(this).attr("class") + '" id="' + $(this).attr("id") + '">';
    li_text = $(this).html();
    final_content += container_ul + li_text + '</ul>';
});
```

so final_content will have the block of code you want, from here you can decide what to do with that block of code. Probably not the prettiest way to get the content but it should work

Comment: $this_li.find('specific_selector').html(temp);

specific_selector ??? meaning ???

Comment: specific_selector as in whatever selector you need to define, since the one you had before does not work. do you understand my answer? you need to target the right selector with your find(), right now your being too general that's why it does not work

Comment: I understand that i'm being too general in the definition. But i don't know how to fix it.... 
I get the part with the 'temp += '<span ....

But I don't get the 'specific_selector' part - where to put it and how to define it...

Comment: ok so you dont understand my answer I will edit it to give you an example, and you should look up css selectors > and see what it does

Comment: i know what css selectors does. But i'm just trying to learn js.

Comment: in that case then look up jquery find(), inside the (), you can use any css selector. basically, anything that you know how to target with css, you can apply it in the selector area

Comment: The issue is that on the children the code returns the parent name in the span instead of the childs own name. How can i fix this??

Comment: what do you mean by name? be more specific, the ID? class? content? in the code you have given or the code I used, which part of it are you trying to grab. li_text = $main_menu.find('a').html(); this line doesn't work right?

Comment: The name MEDIA is the page name or headline in Wordpress. the li_text in the span inserts this text/name into the span after class.
This should be the childs name on children. NOT the name of the parent li. Do you understand me?

Comment: I think it has to do with this line.

    li_text = $this_li.find('a').html();

This needs to "pull" the right name from the right li a.

Comment: not really, write out the ideal result html markup, the code you posted is what is generated with your js I assume, so put a simple example of the code you want the js to generate

Comment: just doing it short.

    <ul id="sub-menu" class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li id="menu-item-67" class="mcdu_sub mcdu_right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67">
        <a href="http://fl370.com/?page_id=60">
          <span class="main_text">
            <span class="main_text">BILLEDER</span>
            <span class="menu_slide">BILLEDER</span>
          </span>
          <span class="menu_slide">
            <span class="main_text">VIDEO</span>
            <span class="menu_slide">VIDEO</span>
          </span>

Comment: my goodness, use the code example I have in my answer and just tell me which target is the one you need lol or better yet, edit the question and paste the html block you are trying to get

Comment: i have to look at this after my meeting, goto www.jsfiddle.net and create the example i will look at it after

Comment: The span should only take it's name from it's parent li a. NOT the top li a

Comment: see my updated answer, you should be able to figure it out from here, do some trail and errors

Comment: I still don't get it. I will still need to apply the span sections as per this:

var$ $main_menu = $('#main_menu');


            $main_menu.find('li').each( function(){
        var $this_li = $(this),
            li_text = $this_li.find('a').html();

        $this_li.find('a').html( '<span class="main_text">' + li_text + '</span>' + '<span class="menu_slide">' + li_text + '</span>' )
    } );

Comment: i dunno what you mean by apply the span section, you said you wanted that block of code from the original block you have, and what I listed has that. Create a simpler example with a fewer elements and state exactly what you want as the result. or post the ideal result code. just edit the entire question and get rid any code that is not needed

Comment: yes but I still need to apply it to the menu - otherwise the menu will come out wrong.... how can i show you what i mean???

Comment: You might find a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) more useful for discussing this, as long as any useful changes make it back here afterward.

Comment: he can't chat says the rep is too low. if you understand what he wants please tell me

Comment: edit the question and simplify the code to basics, then explain or show the code you want as result. So have your simplified code in question, then the code result you would like to see